# Toshiba Laptop Not Booting CD/DVD Drive on Laptop Start

Tags: windows, boot

I am running Windows 8 on my laptop and I have turned off "Quick Start" and "Secure Boot." Also CD/DVD is the primary boot option in BIOS.

However, still my laptop won't boot the cd thats inserted.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**CD/DVD** bad/damaged/not suitable for booting this system

CD/DVD **Drive** bad/damaged. I had one (on a brand-new system) that caused me to think I had bad boot media and all sorts of other things I could think of until I swapped in a good drive, and everything worked right again.